# how to use a customised message instead of showing "No result found" for a table values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, elasticsearch-8

In ELK 8.7v Kibana how to use a customised message instead of showing "No result found" for a table values,
Main Goals :

> To show the table result if data present ;
> if there is no data than instead of showing "No result found" its should have some message as per user needs(Customised)"

Suggest me:

Expected to have a clear steps to follow

> if there is 0 value or Count = 0 then customised message; so that client can understand the table current status as per the timestamp.